# Obtener solo un dato de un json

Tags: reactjs, fetch

tengo un problema, que he buscado e intendado soluciones, pero ninguna me funcionó. Mi problema es el siguiente, tengo un json, hago un fetch, bien, el tema es que quiero destacar una posición en concreto, la quiero colocar en una `card` y asi quedar mas bonito. Pero claro, al hacerlo como lo tengo, pone todos los elementos del json en una `card` nueva.
Bueno, mi fetch es básico:

```
export default () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const url = "Datos.json";
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState();
  const fetchApi = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const responseJSON = await response.json();
    setTodos(responseJSON);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchApi();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      {/*{props.data.rows.map((item, indx) => {*/}
      {!todos
        ? "Cargando..."
        : todos.map((todo, index) => {
            var dta = [];
            var date = new Date(todo.dt * 1000);
            var hours = "0" + date.getHours();
            var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();
            var formattedTime =
              hours.substr(-2) +
              ":" +
              minutes.substr(-2); /*+ ':' + seconds.substr(-2)*/
            dta.push(formattedTime);
            console.log(todos);
            return (
              <div>
                <Typography>{todo.Competicion}:</Typography>
                <Typography variant="h1" gutterBottom>
                  {dta} {todo.evento} {/* EVENTO DESTACADO, DEBE SER 1 O 2 COMO MAXIMO, MAS ADELANTE REEMPLAZO POR LA CARD CON IMG, ETC... */}
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>
                  {dta} {todo.evento} {/* TODOS LOS EVENTOS (INCLUYENDO LOS DESTACADOS) */}
                </Typography>
                <OldButtons {...todo} />
              </div>
            );
          })}
      {/*})}*/}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Como determinas el objeto a destacar? Porque si por ejemplo quieres solo los elementos 1 y 2 de tu lista  sean destacados puedes emplear el index del map y sabes en que posición están dichos elementos.

Comment: Claro, yo si se en que posición, como si fuera un array, por ejemplo, pueden estar en la posición 14, y 18, por ejemplo, pero ahi, en la card lo pongo manualmente, al menos hasta que busque otra solucion